# Fast weighted random selection from very large set of values

Tags: c++, random, selection, complexity-theory, probability

I'm currently working on a problem that requires the random selection of an element from a set. Each of the elements has a weight(selection probability) associated with it.

My problem is that for sets with a small number of elements say 5-10, the complexity (running time) of the solution I was is acceptable, however as the number of elements increases say for 1K or 10K etc, the running time becomes unacceptable.

My current strategy is:

1. Select random value X with range [0,1)
2. Iterate elements summing their weights until the sum is greater than X
3. The element which caused the sum to exceed X is chosen and returned

For large sets and a large number of selections this process begins to exhibit quadratic behavior, in short is there a faster way? a better algorithm perhaps?

Comment: You should remove the C++ tag, as this is a general algorithm question applicable to any language.

Comment: Thats true, but I'd prefer solutions in C++, as the problem I'm coding is in C++

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming that the element weights are fixed, you can work with precomputed sums. This is like working with the cumulative probability function directly, rather than the density function.

The lookup can then be implemented as a binary search, and hence be log(N) in the number of elements.

A binary search obviously requires random_access to the container of the weights.

Alternatively, use a `std::map<>` and the `upper_bound()` method.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
  std::map<double, char> cumulative;
  typedef std::map<double, char>::iterator It;

  cumulative[.20]='a';
  cumulative[.30]='b';
  cumulative[.40]='c';
  cumulative[.80]='d';
  cumulative[1.00]='e';

  const int numTests = 10;
  for(int i = 0;
      i != numTests;
      ++i)
  {
      double linear = rand()*1.0/RAND_MAX;  
      std::cout << linear << "\t" << cumulative.upper_bound(linear)->second << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you mean use stl upper_bound lower_bound? could you provide a quick example?

Comment: @Curzon: To apply Keith's suggestion to your code, rather than assigning a weight to all of your elements, assign the weight + the sum of the preceding weights. Then, select a random value X [0,1), and use set::lower_bound to obtain an iterator to the element whose value is _not less than_ X. (Alternately, use upper_bound if the element should be strictly greater than X)

Answer (score 16):

You want to use the Walker algorithm.  With N elements, there's a set-up
cost of O(N).  However, the sampling cost is O(1).  See

- A. J. Walker, An Efficient Method for Generating
  Discrete Random Variables and General Distributions, ACM TOMS 3, 253-256
  (1977).
- Knuth, TAOCP, Vol 2, Sec 3.4.1.A.

The RandomSelect class of [a RandomLib](http://randomlib.sf.net)
implements this algorithm.

Comment: A bit late to help to OP, but for future readers, this is the right answer. An O(1) algorithm is better than an O(log n) algorithm any day of the week,

Comment: From C++11 on: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution

Comment: can you share an example? :)

Comment: Check Knuth's textbook for a description of the algorithm.  The link to RandomLib gives you an implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a quick enough way to sample a random element uniformly, you can use rejection sampling; all you need to know is the maximum weight.  It would work as follows: Suppose the maximum weight is M.  Pick a number X uniformly in [0,1].  Sample elements repeatedly until you find one whose weight is at least M*X; choose this one.

Or, an approximate solution: pick 100 elements uniformly at random; choose one proportional to weight within this set.