# How can SQL create duplicate records?

Tags: sql

I was having a look at this question: [Getting random value from a SQLite table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068099/getting-random-value-from-a-sqlite-table) and it got me wondering if one can duplicate records using SQL. More specifically, is there a construct that allows to transform these records:

```
id| name| count
---------------
 1| Anne|     3
 2|  Joe|     2
```

into:

```
id| name
--------
 1| Anne
 1| Anne
 1| Anne
 2|  Joe
 2|  Joe
```

where the count of `Anne` and `Joe` records in the latter matches the corresponding `count` value in the former set of records.

Can it be done with SQL? If so, how?

**EDIT:**

Lucero asks what SQL dialect; any really, but ideally the most agnostic approach would be the best.

**ANOTHER EDIT:**

Can it be done within a single SQL statement in say sqlite?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a "numbers" table (it's handy for various operations):

```
CREATE TABLE num
( i UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (i)
) ;

INSERT INTO num (i)
VALUES
  (1), (2), ..., (1000000) ;
```

Then:

```
SELECT 
    t.id, t.name
FROM 
        tableX AS t
    JOIN
        num
            ON num.i <= t."count"
```

**Warning**: There is of course a limitation on this approach. The query will not produce all the wanted rows, as soon as you have a value in the `count` column that exceeds the maximum value stored in the Numbers table. If the values in the `count` column are unbounded, then only an iterative or recursive solution (like the other two answers) can work.

Comment: Ha nice join on the all the `num` records with `i<=count`

Answer (score 8):

What SQL dialect and version? It can eaily be done with a recursive CTE.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, name, count FROM tbl
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, name, count-1 FROM cte WHERE count>1
)
SELECT id, name FROM cte
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using a recursive CTE:

```
;WITH CTE_Data as (
    select id=1, name='Anne',[COUNT]=3
    union select id=2, name='Joe',[COUNT]=2
),
CTE_List as (
    select
        id,
        name,
        ind=1
    from CTE_Data
    union all
    select
        l.id,
        l.name,
        ind=ind+1
    from CTE_List l
        join CTE_Data d on l.id = d.id
    where 
        l.ind < d.[count]
)
select id,name from CTE_List
order by id,ind
```

NOTE: CTE_List is the interesting one, CTE_Data is just the source data for testing.