# How to duplicate records in SQL output

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates

My question is identical to the one in [How can SQL create duplicate records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070816/how-can-sql-create-duplicate-records).  However, I'm trying to do it in Access, and none of the solutions there appear to be applicable.  Preferably, I'd like a single SQL statement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer from that linked question can be adapted for Access.  Create your `num` table from the user interface.  If you want to create the table with a DDL statement, use this.

```
Dim strDdl As String
strDdl = "CREATE TABLE num (" & vbCrLf & _
    "i INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" & vbCrLf & _
    ");"
Debug.Print strDdl
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strDdl
```

Load the `num` table.  In Access, a VBA procedure would be convenient.

```
Public Sub Load_Num_table()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim x As Long

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("num", dbOpenTable, dbAppendOnly)
    For x = 1 To 100
        rs.AddNew
        rs!i = x
        rs.Update
    Next x
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

With your `num` table prepared and your other table named *tableX*, use this SQL statement to return a row set with duplicated rows.

```
SELECT t.id, t.name
FROM
    tableX AS t
    INNER JOIN num 
    ON num.i <= t.count;
```

The only real difference in that `SELECT` statement vs. the one suggested by @ypercube in the accepted answer to that other question is `INNER JOIN` instead of just `JOIN`.  Access' db engine won't accept `JOIN` alone; you must specify the join type (inner, left, or right).

Answer (score 0):

Insert Into TableName (field 1, field 2, ...)
  Select * From TableName;

if u have primary key will give error.