# C++ Inverted Weighted Shuffle/Random

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, selection, weighted

I have a list of weighted objects i.e.:

`A->1 B->1 C->3 D->2 E->3`

is there an efficient algorithm in C++ to pick random elements according to their weight?

For example The possibility that element A or B with a lower weighting is picked is higher (30%) than the possibility that the algorithm selects elements C E (10%) or D (20%)

Comment: The answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052603 should solve this.  You may need to normalise your weights by dividing each weight by the total sum of all weights.

Comment: You don't really need to normalize. just make the random range goes [0,total weight) instead of [0,1)

Comment: thanks! but if I understand aright, this algorithm works only if the weighting is "normal": pick a element with a higher possibility if it's weighting is high.

Comment: If the weights were 1,1,100,7,100, would the probabilities be the same? (Meaning the actual values play no role, only the order.) Regardless, I think we need a bit more details into exact you want the probabilities to be distributed.

Comment: I think it should work with this method if i simply invert the values: A->1/1 B->1/1 C->1/3 D->1/2 E->1/3 ..
@Dukeling no: if the weights were 1,1,100,7,100 the probabilities would also change

Comment: @user1086229 Summing those up gives 19/6. I assume you then normalize by dividing those inverted weights by the sum. That gives P(A)=P(B)=0.315, P(C)=P(E)=0.105 and P(D)=0.158.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Dukeling said, we need more info. Like how you interpret and use the selection chance.

At least in the field of evolutionary algorithm, **fitness scaling** (or selection chance scaling) is a sizable topic.

Suppose you start with **badness** score

```
B[i] = how badly you don't want to select the i-th item
```

And the objective is to calculate **fitness**/selection score `S[i]` which I assume you are to use it in [roulette wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_proportionate_selection) fashion.

As you say, one obvious way is to use multiplicative inverse:

```
S[i] = 1 / B[i]
```

However, there might be a little problem with that.
The the same amount of change in `B[i]` with low value has so much more impact than the same amount of change when `B[i]` already has high value.

Ask yourself this:

```
Say
B[1] = 1     ->     S[1] = 1
B[2] = 2     ->     S[2] = 0.5
So item 1 is twice times as likely to be selected compared to item 2

But with the same amount of change
B[3] = 1000  ->     S[3] = 0.001
B[4] = 1001  ->     S[4] = 0.000999001
Item 3 is only 1.001 times as likely to be selected compared to item 4
```

I'll just throw one possible alternative scheme here for now.

```
S[i] = max(B) - B[i] + 1
```

The `+ 1` part helps so no item has zero chance to be selected.

This ends the part of calculating selection score.

---

Next, let's clear up how to use the selection score in roulette wheel fashion.
Assume we decided to use the **additive inverse** scheme.

```
B[1] = 1     ->     S[1] = 1001
B[2] = 2     ->     S[2] = 1000
B[3] = 1000  ->     S[3] = 2
B[4] = 1001  ->     S[4] = 1
```

Then imagine each point in the score is correspond to a lottery ticket.
Let's assign the ticket a running IDs.

```
| Item | Score = #ticket |   ticket ID  |         win chance       |
|   1  |      1001       | 0    to 1000 |  1001/2004 ~ 0.499500998 |
|   2  |      1000       | 1001 to 2000 |  1000/2004 ~ 0.499001996 |
|   3  |         2       | 2001 to 2002 |     2/2004 ~ 0.000998004 |
|   4  |         1       | 2003 to 2003 |     1/2004 ~ 0.000499002 |
```

There are 2004 tickets in total.

To do a selection, pick the winning ticket ID at random i.e. the random range is [0,2004).
**Binary search** can be used to quickly look up which item owns the winning ticket as you have already seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052603). What needs to be looked up with binary search are the **boundary** values of ticket ID which are `1001,2001,2003` rather than the score themselves.

---

For comparison, here is the selection chance in case the **multiplicative inverse** scheme is used.

```
| Item |                    win chance         |
|   1  |           1/1.501999001 ~ 0.665779404 |
|   2  |         0.5/1.501999001 ~ 0.332889702 |
|   3  |       0.001/1.501999001 ~ 0.000665779 |
|   4  | 0.000999001/1.501999001 ~ 0.000665114 |
```

You can notice that in the additive inverse scheme, 1 unit of badness **consistently** corresponds to around a difference of 0.0005 in selection chance.

Whereas in multiplicative inverse scheme, 1 unit of badness results in **varying** difference of selection chance.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer! I think that is exactly what I am seeking for.
to continue with your example, we would have values like
S[1] = 1001, S[2] = 1000, S[3] = 2, S[4] = 1
Now we use the algorithm shown in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052603
And now i select a random number in the range [0,max(B)=1001).
Isn't there the probabity much higher that B[2] is picked than B[1]?

Comment: Sorry: the possibility that B[3] gets picked that B[4] is in this case higher (upper_bound)

Comment: @user1086229 From your comment, I can see you have misunderstood/misapplied the selection score. Allow me to elaborate in edit.